# How do I check if the value is defined for a key of an object in Parse Android?

Tags: android, object, parse-platform, key

Say I have an Object `Parent` containing `Name` as one of the keys. I gotta do a task only after checking if the value say `Tom` is available under the key `Name`. This is kind of checking for username and password but Parse handles it with inbuilt code.

How do I check for the availability of value for a key in an object in Parse Android?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this buddy..

```
private void checkingKey(){
   ParseQuery<ParseObject> lookUp = ParseQuery.getQuery("Parent");
   lookUp.whereEqualTo("Name",key);
   lookUp.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
       @Override
       public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
           if(e==null && list.size()!=0){
               //KEY FOUND //
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),list.get(0).get("Name").toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }else{
               //Error fetching Key
           }
       }
   });
```

}